# How do I code _.reduce()?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, native-code

I need to recreate _.reduce() in javascript such that it should

1. Be able to Sum up an array
2. Use the first element as an accumulator if non is given
3. not invoke the iterator on the first element when using it as an accumulator
4. invoke the iterator on the first element when given an accumulator

So far I have a function that fulfills the 1st and 4th requirements. I am having trouble getting the 2nd and 3rd however.

```
_.reduce = function(collection, iterator, accumulator) {
if(typeof accumulator === undefined){
  accumulator = collection[0]
}
_.each(collection, function(anyItem){
  accumulator = iterator(accumulator, anyItem);
})
return accumulator;
};
```

What is my next step and how do I complete this function?

Comment: [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) returns a string, so your if condition should be `=== "undefined"`

Comment: Why? Underscore already has a `_.reduce` function. And in vanilla-js you can use `[].reduce`.

Comment: Because it's homework.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  _.reduce = function(collection, iterator, accumulator) {
    if (arguments[0] && arguments[1] && arguments.length === 2) {
      accumulator = collection[0];
      collection = collection.slice(1);
    }

    _.each(collection, function(item) {
      accumulator = iterator(accumulator, item);
    });

    return accumulator;
  };
```

If you don't understand part of it, just ask, i'll try to explain.

Comment: What if someone wants to use `undefined` as the accumulator? It's rare in practice but still I would suggest to check the length of `arguments` instead.

Comment: either they pass undefined as value or omit it, first if will catch both. You can also use if (accumulator === void 0) basically it's the same thing.

Comment: @SpiderPig is right. The requirement was to start iteration at the second value when an accumulator is provided. If someone provides the value `undefined`, it should not enter the `if` statement.

Comment: if accumulator is omitted or passed as undefined, pls read what the code inside the if block does. assigns first item in collection as accumulator, and slices out the 1st item and updates the collection with the remaining items.

Comment: Open a js console and compare the results of these two expressions. `[1,2,3].reduce((a,b) => a + ", " + b)` and `[1,2,3].reduce((a,b) => a + ", " + b, undefined)`. In the second case you get `'undefined, 1, 2, 3'` which is exactly what you should get.

Comment: That looks nice. But if you decide to check for illegal input it's better to throw an error. Your checks for `arguments[0]` and `[1]` are not really doing anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

I would write it like this

```
_.reduce = function(collection, iterator, accumulator) {
  if(arguments.length < 3) return _.reduce(collection.slice(1), iterator, collection[0]);
  _.each(collection, item => accumulator = iterator(accumulator, item));

  return accumulator;
};
```